# How to soften/feather image edges using box-shadow in slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image slider. In order to have a shoother view I want to show image edges feathered when rolling.

I have tried to use `box-shadow` property but it did not help me. It is possible to feather image edges using an image editor. But I do not want that.

I have added an additional `<div class="insetShadow">` next to `<img>`.

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="insetShadow"></div>
</div>

.insetShadow
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px 5px #fff;
    z-index: 20;
}

.carousel  img
{
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 19;

}
```

`box-shadow` is not applicable to `img` element when `inset` feature enabled.

In the up-left picture you may see the actual view and in the bottom-right desired view.
Is there any other css solution for that or any jQuery plugin?

[image]

Comment: How was `box-shadow` not helpful? It looks to me that it's actually the best solution for your needs.

Comment: @MaxArt the question is about how to use box-shadow to accomplish. And yes I agree, it is the best way to do this if there's no interests in using any image-editing programs.

Comment: you want the shadow to be INSIDE the photo and not outside, yes?

Comment: @florin.prisecariu yes my friend. I want shadow to be inside the photo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a [spread radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) of at least half of the blur radius:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px 6px #fff;
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vesay/4/edit)

Comment: @zkanoca Added a demo.

Comment: OMG! Do you think you can apply it to image? Come on!

Comment: My images are not  background. They are `<img>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generator to mess up with the box-shadow properly. It's just CSS and attach it to the slideshow element with jQuery.

[Check this and work around!](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)